# How to assign any key in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

You can assign the A key to move my characters in my flash game and if you can how ?

```
     playerOne.y = mouseY;
}

function movePlayerTwo(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) { playerTwo.y = playerTwo.y - 20; }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) { playerTwo.y = playerTwo.y + 20; }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be incorrectly tagged as _JavaScript_ when it is about _Action Script 3_.

Comment: @PaulS. I have corrected the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value for the `A` key is 65:

```
if(evt.keyCode === 65)
{
    // Do movement.
}
```

You can look up some others [here](https://github.com/MartyWallace/Lotus/blob/master/Lotus/Source/lotus/base/Input.as).

Comment: He could also do `String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)` and then check directly for equality to "a".

Answer (score 0):

On a listener

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
```

and

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
```

you simply listen if ANY key is pressed. In the handlers onDown() and onUp() you need to check witch key was actually pressed. Usually it's done with a switch to keep the code tidy. Here's an example:

```
private function onDown(e:Event):void
{
   switch(e.keyCode)
   {
      case 65: // this is the keycode for key "a"
      keyAPressed = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

For movement it's a good idea to make a few variables, like

```
private var isMoving:Boolean = false;
private var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
private var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
private var goingLeft:Boolean = false;
```

with this you can have better controls with a loop like this:

```
private function movementLoop():void
{
   if (! isMoving)
   return; // if the char's not moving it's safe to return the function
   if (goingLeft)
   x -= movementSpeed;
   else
   x += movementSpeed;
}
```

You can use this site to check the keyCodes for every button: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/using_keyboard_as3.htm

As you can see from this example the movement are handled on a loop that can be called by a timer or ENTER_FRAME event, not from the press of a button. It's important for many reasons, few of them are:

- You're not spamming the movement command by holding the key down.
- Your keyboard handler is smaller and cleaner to read and extend with new implementation
- You can make a NPC move with same methods by modifying the isMoving and direction variables
- Same as above goes to sending this data to server in multiplayer games
- If you press both left and right, the variables can switch direction of the movement, not try to move the player both left and right.

Hope I could answer your question.

Good luck!